# RadMaskedTextBox How to showing last 4 characters?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I want to create a mask in a textbox (RadMaskedTextBox) that is showing the last 4 characters. But what I see is the first 4 characters. What do I wrong?

- DataBindings is set to a field of a string number of 9 character.
  (SQL  Server/LINQ-to-SQL) in property Value.
- Mask is set to "*****0000".
- MaskType is set to Standard.

[image]

Comment: Sorry that's the same result. Thank you for your answer

Comment: The [RadMaskedTextBox](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/maskedtextbox/functionality/basics/defaultcs.aspx) is actually not meant for your use case, isn't it?

Comment: Strange... but you're right. If you need to make a mask with an event. I do not really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar behavior with any textbox (or maskedTextBox with empty mask) using the _Leave event.

```
    private void maskedTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = maskedTextBox1.Text;
        maskedTextBox1.Text = new string('*', text.Length - 4) + text.Substring(text.Length - 4);
    }
```